# Apache James, adding domain

Tags: james

I only try to add domain but get connection refused exception:
The command line i tried, and below the exceptions:

```
sudo ./james-cli.sh -h localhost -p 9999 adddomain mydomain.tld
```

Output:

```
 java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:357)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
        at org.apache.james.cli.probe.impl.JmxServerProbe.connect(JmxServerProbe.java:93)
        at org.apache.james.cli.probe.impl.JmxServerProbe.<init>(JmxServerProbe.java:68)
        at org.apache.james.cli.ServerCmd.main(ServerCmd.java:104)
    Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:203)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1924)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1891)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:274)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:114)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem until I actually issued the command in root. Change to root on the command line by typing su and it will ask for a password. Then you should be able to change the james settings.

Comment: i was sudo, but i can not remember how did i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Something strange is going on there. I have this problem also from time to time and I am not really sure how it was solved.

Last time i had it disappeared after I started james server which was not started. Before that I solved it with sudo, but with absolute path to the james-cli.sh

I have strange feeling that there is something not working properly in james' RMI.